# Adding radio input dynamically doesn't work with others with the same name

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, radio-button

Imagine the problem: I have a form with 3 radio inputs with the same name and i have a button which adds another radio input with the same name as those first 3. The problem is that after i add another radio field via the button the radio doesn't cooperate with those first 3 radios(it is like it adds another one group for those radios).

To see the problem press few times "Add Line" button, than play with radio buttons. The first 3 default radios are in one group and the added one are in different group.

Can someone tell me how to make all of those radios cooperate with each others(be like in one group)?

The code:

```js
function addAnswer(value) {
  thebutton = value;
  console.log(value);
  table = document.getElementById("thetable");
  row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

  cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="answer[]" required style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Wpisz tutaj odpowiedź">';
  cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="radio" value="' + value + '" name="correct">';

  document.getElementById("addbutton").value = parseInt(value) + 1;

}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" id="thetable">
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 80%;">Odpowiedź</td>
      <td style="width: 20%;">Poprawna</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="answer[]" required style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Wpisz tutaj odpowiedź">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" id="radio0" name="correct" value="0">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="answer[]" required style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Wpisz tutaj odpowiedź">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="correct" value="1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="answer[]" required style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Wpisz tutaj odpowiedź">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="correct" value="2">
      </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<button type="button" value="3" id="addbutton" onclick="addAnswer(this.value)" style="width: auto; height: auto;">Add line</button>
<input type="hidden" name="questionId" value="<?php echo $id[0]['id']; ?>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you switch these two lines, the table is inside the form. Perhaps that will solve your issue:

```
<table style="width: 100%;" id="thetable">
  <form action="" method="POST">
```

```js
function addAnswer(value) {
  thebutton = value;
  console.log(value);
  table = document.getElementById("thetable");
  row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

  cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="answer[]" required style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Wpisz tutaj odpowiedź">';
  cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="radio" value="' + value + '" name="correct">';

  document.getElementById("addbutton").value = parseInt(value) + 1;

}
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
    <table style="width: 100%;" id="thetable">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 80%;">Odpowiedź</td>
      <td style="width: 20%;">Poprawna</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="answer[]" required style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Wpisz tutaj odpowiedź">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" id="radio0" name="correct" value="0">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="answer[]" required style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Wpisz tutaj odpowiedź">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="correct" value="1">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="answer[]" required style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Wpisz tutaj odpowiedź">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="correct" value="2">
      </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<button type="button" value="3" id="addbutton" onclick="addAnswer(this.value)" style="width: auto; height: auto;">Add line</button>
<input type="hidden" name="questionId" value="<?php echo $id[0]['id']; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: Oh my god, such a stupid mistake stopped my work for 2 hours. Your solution is correct, thank you.